# How to convert a single record to multiple records in redshift or mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the table below,

```
Project | # of Months | Monthly Fee  |  Start Date
a       |      3      | 1000         |  1/1/2015
```

I want to convert the single row table above to multiple rows according to the number of months, we get the revenue. E.g. if the contract is for 3 months starting from Jan 1, then there should be 3 rows, for each month that we get the revenue. How would I do this?

```
Project|  Fee   |  Month
a      |  1000  |  1/1/2015
a      |  1000  |  2/1/2015
a      |  1000  |  3/1/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with numbers up to the maximum number of months that you need to allow:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    num INT PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
```

Then you can join with this table:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (project, fee, month) 
SELECT project, monthly_fee, DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL num MONTH)
FROM old_table
JOIN numbers ON num < num_of_months;
```